# Significant drop in battery life on new laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, acer-aspire, battery-life

I got an [Acer Aspire V Nitro](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834315130) about 4 months ago and I've noticed a really large drop in battery life lately, despite attempts to fix that.

Unless I really need it (games, which I *rarely* play, or graphics computing), I keep the processor maximum at 50% both on battery and plugged in. My screen brightness is typically no more than 2 notches up, and the only applications I have running all the time are Firefox, and Skype.

When I first got it, there were some issues, but after a couple full cycles I was able to get about 5-6 hours. Usually, I try to keep it between 20% and 80%.

However, in the past month or so, I have been using my desktop more, and so my laptop stayed in my bag except when using it at uni. I've noticed a significant drop in battery life (about 4 hours max, even though the tooltip over the battery icon usually says no more than 2 hours (!)).

I've uninstalled a lot of bloatware, and turned off all unnecessary start up expenses. Any ideas on what could be going on, how I can check, or how to increase it again?

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention that my wife dropped the laptop about 3 weeks ago (about the time that the battery life started degrading). I listened to the bottom of the laptop, and there's a small clicking/buzzing sound, like a couple of insects flying around. I didn't think that could affect battery life, but maybe?

Comment: When in your bag, is it in Sleep mode or is it in true Hibernate mode, which uses *no* power?

Comment: I have it set to hibernate when closed.

Comment: Any ideas? I literally cannot think of a reason that the battery would suddenly "become bad"

Comment: If it's not running something when off (e.g. a task such as disk optimization waking it), then check what is running using Task Manager or Process Explorer. Are any processes consuming unusual amounts of CPU time?

Comment: Nope. Firefox was using a lot of RAM, so I switched over to Chrome (since I've heard of FF leaks), but it's still kinda crappy. Nothing's using too much CPU, either.

Comment: I'm curious... is it still there the buzzing? ...and the battery? :-) Note that it's difficult to understand only from the sounds, but if it is a buzz like, in little, the ones of the Frankenstein lab, then it could be an electric arc, with little voltage, acting as an intermittent short circuit that can help to discharge the battery. It depends from the amperage of the circuit branch. More easily it can be some noise from the computer vibration that should not affect the life of the battery. Did you try with another battery?

Comment: There is still a buzzing. I'm worried that it may be the heat sink or something.